# PHP - Get path minus root

Tags: php, forms, post, get

So I have this link:

http://kenthomes.net/Amelia-Cove (We use an alias system.)

Then I open a pop-up iframe (http://kenthomes.net/shareplan.php?mod=39)

How I can I pass the string "Amelia-Cove" to that page?

My best guess was to make the link = to http://kenthomes.net/shareplan.php?mod=39&plan=Amelia-Cove

But how to I retrieve only "Amelia-Cove" from the initial page?

Comment: some code would be helpful, do you have any or are you just planning?

Comment: Perhaps you can store it as cookie or in the session and access it in your next page..

Comment: <?php $plan = $_GET['plan'] ?>

Comment: kkhugs got it, thanks guys! Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

In your above example, this would have a value of: `/Amelia-Cove`. If you want to get rid of the `/`, try this:

`trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET protocol to receive parameters in the URL:

```
http://kenthomes.net/shareplan.php?mod=39&plan=Amelia-Cove
```

then fetch these parameters through the PHP GET global variable:

```
$_GET['plan']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming OP will not always fetch Amelia-Cove but rather want that part of the url and used Amelia-Cove as an example and knows how to use $_GET

To fetch that part of the url and pass it through $_GET I would suggest using this:

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

[Full `parse_url` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)