# PHP - Get the end of a URL

Tags: php, post, get

So I think I need to submit a new question for this...

Here is my old question: [PHP - Get path minus root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842455/php-get-path-minus-root/15842594?noredirect=1#15842594)

I need a way in PHP to take the URL being any of the following...

```
http://kenthomes.net/plan_detail.php?mod=39
http://kenthomes.net/Amelia-Cove
```

and get everything after leaving me with...

```
"plan_detail.php?mod=39" // If there is no alias for that page
```

OR

```
"Amelia-Cove" // If that page has an alias being applied
```

In reality, they are the same page, because of the alias, but not all of these pages have aliases associated with them such as...

```
http://kenthomes.net/plan_detail.php?mod=52
```

unlike...

```
http://kenthomes.net/Amelia-Cove
```

Currently I am using...

```
trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/')
```

which gives me...

```
"Amelia-Cove" // Which is fine.
```

OR

```
"plan_detail.php" // Which is not okay.
```

I need..

```
"Amelia-Cove" // Which is fine.
```

OR

```
"plan_detail.php?mod=39" // Which is fine.
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` should work, or you can check `QUERY_STRING`

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should give you what you need. Just try `var_dump($_SERVER);` and see what fits you the best.

Answer (score 5):

You can get all the parts of an URL via [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

For example;

```
$parts = parse_url('http://kenthomes.net/plan_detail.php?mod=39');

print_r($parts);
```

Should give you something like this:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => kenthomes.net
    [path] => /plan_detail.php
    [query] => mod=39
)
```

Which you can use to create your own URL containing the parts that you need

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` only contains the URI.

When you also want the part after the `?`, you need to also use `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`.

Use:

```
trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query string (the bit after the question mark), via `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 0):

Append `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

[PHP: $_SERVER - Manual](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), and if you just want the far right, using [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) would be sufficient.

```
$data = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Should be enough.

Otherwise if responding to the current request, [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) might work, as that is the entire URI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

echo trim($uri . $qs, '/');
```